# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer::setForm()

Tags: methods, undefined, phpmailer, call

here is my code

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require  'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require  'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require  'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

if(isset($_POST["send"])){
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'random@gmail.com'; // Your gmail
$mail->Password = 'rqbsmgrfefohmokx'; // Your gmail password
$mail->SMTPSecure= 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;

$mail->setForm('random@gmail.com'); // Your gmail

$mail->addAdress($_POST["email"]);

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $_POST["subject"];
$mail->Body = $_POST["message"];

$mail->send();

echo
"
<script>
alert('Sent Succesfully');
document.location.href = 'index.php';
</script>

" ;
}
?>
```

i got this error
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer::setForm() in C:\xampp\htdocs\sendmail\send.php:20 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sendmail\send.php on line 20 Any ideas???

I really dont know from what this error comes... so i hope someone to help me/guide me

Comment: SetForm -> SetFrom

Comment: Yeah thanks for help my friend now it gives me this... [link]ibb.co/6wjNHk5

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing to do in situations like this is **read the error message**. In this case the message is telling you that the `setForm` method does not exist. This is correct, and if you go and look at any of the PHPMailer examples or drill into the class itself, you’ll realise that the method name you’re looking for is `setFrom`, with the r and o the other way around.

Comment: Yeah thanks for help my friend now it gives me this... https://ibb.co/6wjNHk5

Comment: That means that it's time to [read some docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#authentication-failures), and to learn how to use exceptions in PHP.